# Multiline regexp in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Hey guys I am pretty new to using regexp. So please bear with me if some of my questions are very basic. I need to filter a large file for some data.
A part of the data file looks like this

```
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
    .
    .
    many more
    .
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
</node>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
</node>
<abcd.....z/>
```

and this pattern repeats multiple times.

My requirement is to get the first `<abcd.....z>` above `</node>` along with the data in between them ( i.e all `<xyz123....etc..etc/>`).

For e.g
output 1:

```
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
    .
    .
    many more
    .
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
```

output 2:

```
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc/>
```

I have used this positive look ahead operator

```
<abcd.*?>(?=</node>)
```

But the main problem with this is that the output includes `<abcd.....z>` which do not have `<xyz123....etc..etc/>` underneath them.
i.e the output is as follows
output 1:

```
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc>
    <xyz123....etc..etc>
    .
    .
    many more
    .
    <xyz123....etc..etc>
```

output 2:

```
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z/>
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc>
</node>
```

If you notice in output 2 i do not need the first 4 `<abcd.....z/>`'s . I need only the last one ie. the output has to be

```
<abcd.....z>
    <xyz123....etc..etc>
```

Again sorry for the long post and hope someone can help me out here!!

Thnaks to @digitalLink i have the right expression.
It is `(<abcd\.*z>(.|\n)*?)(?=<\/node>)`

This works fine with online tools like regexr and regexp101.
I noticed that both tools use a g-modifier (global modifier) at the end of the reg expression. I understand that /g expression flag reatins the index of the last match, allowing iterative searches.

Is this possible in matlab?
Do I have to use g-modifier explicitly in matlab?
What is the equivalent expression flag in matlab

Could someone please help me out here. I am new to matlab and not able to figure out this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this Regex expression may be what you're looking for.
Let me know how it works.

```
"(<abcd\.*z>(.|\n)*?)(?=<\/node>)"
```

Make sure to include the multiline flag.

Test it here:
http://regexr.com/3c0aj

Comment: Hey! thanks for the expression. When i check with online tools like regexr.com or regex101.com it works like a charm. But when i use it in my program in matlab it does not work. I noticed that both regexr.com and regexp101.com use a g-modifier (global modifier) at the end of the reg expression you shared. Do I have to use g-modifier explicitly in matlab? If yes could you please tell me how i can do that? Thanks again

Comment: I understand that /g expression flag reatins the index of the last match, allowing iterative searches. Is this possible in matlab? if yes what is the equivalent expression flag in matlab and how can it be used with the expression you shared?